# how to wrap readkey in bash in a variable

Tags: linux, bash, keypress

I build a Lego remote using lirc and an raspberrypi.

All works fine but now i have a problem. The train needs the ir-signal constantly. I have written this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

while : 
do
  if [ -t 0 ]; then stty -echo -icanon -icrnl time 0 min 0; fi

  keypress=''
  clear;
  echo "Dies ist das Lego

  1 = vorwärts
  2 = rückwärts
  3 = stop
  "
  read -n 1 text
  if [ "$text" = "1" ];
  then
    while [ "x$keypress" = "x" ]; do
      irsend SEND_ONCE LEGO_Combo_Direct  FORWARD_FLOAT
      keypress="`cat -v`"
    done
  fi

  if [ "$text" = "2" ];
  then
    while [ "x$keypress" = "x" ]; do
      irsend SEND_ONCE LEGO_Combo_Direct  BACKWARD_FLOAT
      keypress="`cat -v`"
    done
  fi

  if [ "$text" = "3" ];
  then
    while [ "x$keypress" = "x" ]; do
      irsend SEND_ONCE LEGO_Combo_Direct  BRAKE_BRAKE
      keypress="`cat -v`"
    done
  fi

done
```

My problem is that the script stoppes on the `read -n 1 text`.
If sombody could help me to use the `keypress` for the `$text` the script wont stop anymore.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks a bit overly complex.
How about:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
if [ -t 0 ]; then stty -echo -icanon -icrnl time 0 min 0; fi
    clear;
    echo "Dies ist das Lego

   1 = vorwärts
   2 = rückwärts
   3 = stop
"
keypress=''
command='BRAKE_BRAKE'
while true;
do
    keypress="`cat -v`"
    case "$keypress" in
        "") ;;
        1) command="FORWARD_FLOAT";;
        2) command="BACKWARD_FLOAT";;
        3) command="BRAKE_BRAKE";;
        x) echo "Terminating..."; break;;
    esac
    irsend SEND_ONCE LEGO_Combo_Direct $command
done
```

And for sure you want to add some cleanup code to restore the terminal back to icanon mode....